# solr search based on user

Tags: solr, lucene

I am newbie to solr. So please bear with me.

### Use cases

- User can share his photos to friends or publicly or make it private.
- User can search for people or photos(he should view only public photos, shared with him).

I have denormalized my relational data to solr schema. I have merged the user object & photo object into solr schema
[image: Schema]

So,

- If user jack (user 3) is searching for "picnic" He shouldn't see the photo_1 but see photo_2.
- If user venu is searching for "picnic" He should see the photo_1 and photo_2.

How can I force solr to look into friends_ids, share_level field? can I do with facet.field? Is dynamic fields work for this case? I have read some tutorials but I am not getting clear picture.

Hope you guys shed some light on this. So that I can take forward. I hope this should be possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a string field for `share_level`, with possible value of `private, public, friends`.

You should also have a multiValued field for `friends_ids`,
and it should store each user id instead of the current CSV format

NOTE: you should revised this column type, **NEVER** use CSV in mysql, use a proper entity relationship

So, once you have the field ready, and complete the reindex,
to search for photo will be just:

```
+name:$search +(share_level:public (+share_level:friends +friends_ids:$uid))

$search = picnic
$uid = 3 (jack)
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply! I will get back to you soon! I am not using the csv format in mysql, I have one to many relationship between user & frienship table

Comment: I tried to get users also for same search; +name:venu (-share_level:[* TO *] OR +(share_level:public (+share_level:friends +friend_ids:1))) but its returning photos with share level private also.

Comment: Use the query analyzer, and i think you should use this `+name:venu +(...)`